# Assigning column names dynamically

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to put the values in the columns without having to write the columns name of the grid.In the commented part is what i tried to do.Any help?

```
if(btn.id == "btn_update1") {

                var recordToUpdate = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
                //var gridCoulumnlength=grid.columns.length;
                //for(var i=0;i<gridCoulumnlength;i++){
                //recordToUpdate.set('grid.columns[i]',Ext.getCmp('update_name').getValue());
                recordToUpdate.set('FirstName',Ext.getCmp('update_name').getValue());
                recordToUpdate.set('LastName',Ext.getCmp('update_lastname').getValue());
                recordToUpdate.set('Email',Ext.getCmp('update_email').getValue());
                //}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firts of all, create object with update data.

```
var update = {
  'FirstName': Ext.getCmp('update_name').getValue(),
  'LastName': Ext.getCmp('update_name').getValue(),
  'Email': Ext.getCmp('update_name').getValue()
}
```

Then you can get row data.

```
var recordToUpdate = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0].data;
```

Then loop and put values.

```
for (var key in recordToUpdate) {
   if (update.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      recordToUpdate[key] = update[key];
   }
}
```